# AngularJS http.get not returning any data

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I am pretty new to AngularJS and Coding but I have had some guidance on this but my http.get is not returning any data. I have the following factory and controller embedded in a .js file. and have a corresponding 'ng-repeat' in a html file which I am looking to return the date from a JSON file. When I look at the details within the scope of Chrome Developer Tools it is showing the scope as being returned but had the following

{ 
member: null
 }

Factory and Controller code is as follows

```
app.factory('MemberFactory', ['$http' , function($http)
{
        var api = 
        {
            getMembers : function() 
            {
                return $http.get('../json/members2.json')            
            }, 
            getMembers : function(membernumber) 
            {  // NEW
                 return $http.get('../json/' + membernumber + '.json')
            }
        }
        return api
}])


app.controller('homeController', 
['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'GetTheMember', 
function($scope, $location, $routeParams, GetTheMember) {
             GetTheMember.getmembers($routeParams.membernumber)
                .success(function(data) {
                   $scope.member = data
                   })
                .error(function(err) {
                    $location.path('./404') 
                  })
             $scope.setImage = function(img) {
                  $scope.img = img
               }
      }])
```

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name in JS. There is no polymorphism like you might know it in java, for example. You second MemberFactory function, the one that take an argument, should probably be named `getMember`.

Answer (score 2):

Your factory is named `MemberFactory`. That is what you should inject in the controller instead of GetTheMember. Note also that property names are case sensitive. You must call `getMembers` and not `getmembers`. But because the function takes a member id, better rename it to `getMember`. That way it won't override the other `getMembers` function.

```
app.controller('homeController', 
['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'MemberFactory', 
function($scope, $location, $routeParams, MemberFactory) {
             MemberFactory.getMember($routeParams.membernumber)
                .success(function(data) {
                   $scope.member = data;
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                    $location.path('./404');
                })

             $scope.setImage = function(img) {
                $scope.img = img;
             }
      }])
```